# what is the result of mongo's withTransaction()?

Tags: mongodb

Reading the latest mongo documentation, it is not clear what `session.withTransaction` return. The code shows it returns a Document. So if I want to return 1, should I return {num: 1} and then use it as the following?:

```
results = session.withTransaction(...
   ...
   return {num: 1}
})
console.log(results.num)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Blockquote

Returns: The value produced by the callback function.

[Doc here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Session.withTransaction/), [source code here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/node_modules_mongodb-core_lib_sessions.js.html#line271)